# Preference of TreeSet for Sorting

Tags: java, sorting

I would like to sort an array of elements. As java provides direct utilities for sorting such as with `TreeSet`, `Collections.sort`, `Arrays.sort`.

Which of the following should I prefer in terms of providing sorted order with less time complexity

1. `TreeSet`
2. `Collections.sort`
3. `Arrays.sort`
4. Implementing quick sort as it is better of all merge, insertion, heap

Comment: That depends. Do you allow duplicates? Do you know the total number of elements in advance?

Comment: Without duplicates, and yes supposing for large arrays

Comment: If you don't want duplicates than you should use some kind of Set, depending on number of elements... you can use LinkedHashSet and sort it in Collection.sort which might be faster than using pure TreeSet http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/

Comment: But in terms of Complexity? TreeSet is O(logn)

Comment: If you have an *array*, then `Arrays.sort()` is the way to go. The others require you to first change to another storage method, which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Depends on what you need. `TreeSet` would be internally reorganized on each insertion, while list/array can be populated at first, then sorted. From complexity point of view, `Collections.sort` and `Arrays.sort` have no big difference, since `Collections.sort` uses `Arrays.sort` internally, it just creates array from the `List` and runs `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev i would like to know more about collections.sort using arrays.sort can you include a link which explains this.

Comment: @Abhishek, just look into the source code of `Collections.sort`